# Getting an error while running script on ubuntu jmeter with non gui mode

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter

I am getting an error on running my JMX file on ubuntu(It works perfectly fine on Windows)

Error

```
2019/09/27 06:33:45 ERROR - jmeter.save.SaveService: Conversion error com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration' : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.MissingFieldException
cause-message       : No field 'sentBytes' found in class 'org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration'
class               : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.SampleSaveConfigurationConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/ResultCollector/objProp/value/sentBytes
line number         : 3726
class[1]            : org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.ObjectProperty
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is JMeter version mismatch.

[JMeter version in Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=jmeter) is [JMeter 2.13](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/4-things-you-should-know-about-jmeter-213/) which was released in 2015

[image]

Current JMeter version is [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html) and there were a lot of [changes](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html) since 2.13 including incompatible ones.

So you need to upgrade JMeter to the latest version available from [JMeter downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page, given you run your .jmx script using the same JMeter version it should be successful no matter of which OS is being used.